# Is there anything special I need to do when making a tensorflow lite model for an android application in order for the output to display?

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to make a tensorflow model that runs on an android application using tensorflow lite. The model is an image classification model (convolutional neural network), which uses the softmax and sparse categorical cross-entropy functions. When I run the sample android image classification model on my android device, the model does predictions and displays the output on my screen; however, when I try the same using my own model on the android app, the output is empty. Do I need to do anything extra/special to my model in order for it to work? How would I resolve this problem?

Most of the code I used is the same as what is in the example classification model, except I replaced their model with my own.

The app works properly and displays the output when I use the example model, but not when I use my own

Here is the code for my classifier.java class:

```java
/* Copyright 2019 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
==============================================================================*/

package org.tensorflow.lite.examples.classification.tflite;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.os.Trace;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import org.tensorflow.lite.DataType;
import org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter;
import org.tensorflow.lite.examples.classification.env.Logger;
import org.tensorflow.lite.examples.classification.tflite.Classifier.Device;
import org.tensorflow.lite.gpu.GpuDelegate;
import org.tensorflow.lite.nnapi.NnApiDelegate;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.FileUtil;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.TensorOperator;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.TensorProcessor;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ImageProcessor;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.TensorImage;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ops.ResizeOp;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ops.ResizeOp.ResizeMethod;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ops.ResizeWithCropOrPadOp;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.ops.Rot90Op;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.label.TensorLabel;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.tensorbuffer.TensorBuffer;

/** A classifier specialized to label images using TensorFlow Lite. */
public abstract class Classifier {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = new Logger();

  /** The model type used for classification. */
  public enum Model {
    FLOAT,
    QUANTIZED,
  }

  /** The runtime device type used for executing classification. */
  public enum Device {
    CPU,
    NNAPI,
    GPU
  }

  /** Number of results to show in the UI. */
  private static final int MAX_RESULTS = 3;

  /** The loaded TensorFlow Lite model. */
  private MappedByteBuffer tfliteModel;

  /** Image size along the x axis. */
  private final int imageSizeX;

  /** Image size along the y axis. */
  private final int imageSizeY;

  /** Optional GPU delegate for accleration. */
  private GpuDelegate gpuDelegate = null;

  /** Optional NNAPI delegate for accleration. */
  private NnApiDelegate nnApiDelegate = null;

  /** An instance of the driver class to run model inference with Tensorflow Lite. */
  protected Interpreter tflite;

  /** Options for configuring the Interpreter. */
  private final Interpreter.Options tfliteOptions = new Interpreter.Options();

  /** Labels corresponding to the output of the vision model. */
  private List<String> labels;

  /** Input image TensorBuffer. */
  private TensorImage inputImageBuffer;

  /** Output probability TensorBuffer. */
  private final TensorBuffer outputProbabilityBuffer;

  /** Processer to apply post processing of the output probability. */
  private final TensorProcessor probabilityProcessor;

  /**
   * Creates a classifier with the provided configuration.
   *
   * @param activity The current Activity.
   * @param model The model to use for classification.
   * @param device The device to use for classification.
   * @param numThreads The number of threads to use for classification.
   * @return A classifier with the desired configuration
   */
  public static Classifier create(Activity activity, Model model, Device device, int numThreads)
      throws IOException {
    if (model == Model.QUANTIZED) {
      return new ClassifierQuantizedMobileNet(activity, device, numThreads);
    } else {
      return new ClassifierFloatMobileNet(activity, device, numThreads);
    }
  }

  /** An immutable result returned by a Classifier describing what was recognized. */
  public static class Recognition {
    /**
     * A unique identifier for what has been recognized. Specific to the class, not the instance of
     * the object.
     */
    private final String id;

    /** Display name for the recognition. */
    private final String title;

    /**
     * A sortable score for how good the recognition is relative to others. Higher should be better.
     */
    private final Float confidence;

    /** Optional location within the source image for the location of the recognized object. */
    private RectF location;

    public Recognition(
        final String id, final String title, final Float confidence, final RectF location) {
      this.id = id;
      this.title = title;
      this.confidence = confidence;
      this.location = location;
    }

    public String getId() {
      return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
      return title;
    }

    public Float getConfidence() {
      return confidence;
    }

    public RectF getLocation() {
      return new RectF(location);
    }

    public void setLocation(RectF location) {
      this.location = location;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      String resultString = "";
      if (id != null) {
        resultString += "[" + id + "] ";
      }

      if (title != null) {
        resultString += title + " ";
      }

      if (confidence != null) {
        resultString += String.format("(%.1f%%) ", confidence * 100.0f);
      }

      if (location != null) {
        resultString += location + " ";
      }

      return resultString.trim();
    }
  }

  /** Initializes a {@code Classifier}. */
  protected Classifier(Activity activity, Device device, int numThreads) throws IOException {
    tfliteModel = FileUtil.loadMappedFile(activity, getModelPath());
    switch (device) {
      case NNAPI:
        nnApiDelegate = new NnApiDelegate();
        tfliteOptions.addDelegate(nnApiDelegate);
        break;
      case GPU:
        gpuDelegate = new GpuDelegate();
        tfliteOptions.addDelegate(gpuDelegate);
        break;
      case CPU:
        break;
    }
    tfliteOptions.setNumThreads(numThreads);
    tflite = new Interpreter(tfliteModel, tfliteOptions);

    // Loads labels out from the label file.
    labels = FileUtil.loadLabels(activity, getLabelPath());

    // Reads type and shape of input and output tensors, respectively.
    int imageTensorIndex = 0;
    int[] imageShape = tflite.getInputTensor(imageTensorIndex).shape(); // {1, height, width, 3}
    imageSizeY = imageShape[1];
    imageSizeX = imageShape[2];
    DataType imageDataType = tflite.getInputTensor(imageTensorIndex).dataType();
    int probabilityTensorIndex = 0;
    int[] probabilityShape =
        tflite.getOutputTensor(probabilityTensorIndex).shape(); // {1, NUM_CLASSES}
    DataType probabilityDataType = tflite.getOutputTensor(probabilityTensorIndex).dataType();

    // Creates the input tensor.
    inputImageBuffer = new TensorImage(imageDataType);

    // Creates the output tensor and its processor.
    outputProbabilityBuffer = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(probabilityShape, probabilityDataType);

    // Creates the post processor for the output probability.
    probabilityProcessor = new TensorProcessor.Builder().add(getPostprocessNormalizeOp()).build();

    LOGGER.d("Created a Tensorflow Lite Image Classifier.");
  }

  /** Runs inference and returns the classification results. */
  public List<Recognition> recognizeImage(final Bitmap bitmap, int sensorOrientation) {
    // Logs this method so that it can be analyzed with systrace.
    Trace.beginSection("recognizeImage");

    Trace.beginSection("loadImage");
    long startTimeForLoadImage = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    inputImageBuffer = loadImage(bitmap, sensorOrientation);
    long endTimeForLoadImage = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    Trace.endSection();
    LOGGER.v("Timecost to load the image: " + (endTimeForLoadImage - startTimeForLoadImage));

    // Runs the inference call.
    Trace.beginSection("runInference");
    long startTimeForReference = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    tflite.run(inputImageBuffer.getBuffer(), outputProbabilityBuffer.getBuffer().rewind());
    long endTimeForReference = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    Trace.endSection();
    LOGGER.v("Timecost to run model inference: " + (endTimeForReference - startTimeForReference));

    // Gets the map of label and probability.
    Map<String, Float> labeledProbability =
        new TensorLabel(labels, probabilityProcessor.process(outputProbabilityBuffer))
            .getMapWithFloatValue();
    Trace.endSection();

    // Gets top-k results.
    return getTopKProbability(labeledProbability);
  }

  /** Closes the interpreter and model to release resources. */
  public void close() {
    if (tflite != null) {
      tflite.close();
      tflite = null;
    }
    if (gpuDelegate != null) {
      gpuDelegate.close();
      gpuDelegate = null;
    }
    if (nnApiDelegate != null) {
      nnApiDelegate.close();
      nnApiDelegate = null;
    }
    tfliteModel = null;
  }

  /** Get the image size along the x axis. */
  public int getImageSizeX() {
    return imageSizeX;
  }

  /** Get the image size along the y axis. */
  public int getImageSizeY() {
    return imageSizeY;
  }

  /** Loads input image, and applies preprocessing. */
  private TensorImage loadImage(final Bitmap bitmap, int sensorOrientation) {
    // Loads bitmap into a TensorImage.
    inputImageBuffer.load(bitmap);

    // Creates processor for the TensorImage.
    int cropSize = Math.min(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    int numRoration = sensorOrientation / 90;
    // TODO(b/143564309): Fuse ops inside ImageProcessor.
    ImageProcessor imageProcessor =
        new ImageProcessor.Builder()
            .add(new ResizeWithCropOrPadOp(cropSize, cropSize))
            .add(new ResizeOp(imageSizeX, imageSizeY, ResizeMethod.BILINEAR))
            .add(new Rot90Op(numRoration))
            .add(getPreprocessNormalizeOp())
            .build();
    return imageProcessor.process(inputImageBuffer);
  }

  /** Gets the top-k results. */
  private static List<Recognition> getTopKProbability(Map<String, Float> labelProb) {
    // Find the best classifications.
    PriorityQueue<Recognition> pq =
        new PriorityQueue<>(
            MAX_RESULTS,
            new Comparator<Recognition>() {
              @Override
              public int compare(Recognition lhs, Recognition rhs) {
                // Intentionally reversed to put high confidence at the head of the queue.
                return Float.compare(rhs.getConfidence(), lhs.getConfidence());
              }
            });

    for (Map.Entry<String, Float> entry : labelProb.entrySet()) {
      pq.add(new Recognition("" + entry.getKey(), entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), null));
    }

    final ArrayList<Recognition> recognitions = new ArrayList<>();
    int recognitionsSize = Math.min(pq.size(), MAX_RESULTS);
    for (int i = 0; i < recognitionsSize; ++i) {
      recognitions.add(pq.poll());
    }
    return recognitions;
  }

  /** Gets the name of the model file stored in Assets. */
  protected abstract String getModelPath();

  /** Gets the name of the label file stored in Assets. */
  protected abstract String getLabelPath();

  /** Gets the TensorOperator to nomalize the input image in preprocessing. */
  protected abstract TensorOperator getPreprocessNormalizeOp();

  /**
   * Gets the TensorOperator to dequantize the output probability in post processing.
   *
   * <p>For quantized model, we need de-quantize the prediction with NormalizeOp (as they are all
   * essentially linear transformation). For float model, de-quantize is not required. But to
   * uniform the API, de-quantize is added to float model too. Mean and std are set to 0.0f and
   * 1.0f, respectively.
   */
  protected abstract TensorOperator getPostprocessNormalizeOp();
}
```

Here is ClassiferQuantizedMobileNet.java

```java
/* Copyright 2017 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
==============================================================================*/

package org.tensorflow.lite.examples.classification.tflite;

import android.app.Activity;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.tensorflow.lite.examples.classification.tflite.Classifier.Device;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.TensorOperator;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.ops.NormalizeOp;

/** This TensorFlow Lite classifier works with the quantized MobileNet model. */
public class ClassifierQuantizedMobileNet extends Classifier {

  /**
   * The quantized model does not require normalization, thus set mean as 0.0f, and std as 1.0f to
   * bypass the normalization.
   */
  private static final float IMAGE_MEAN = 0.0f;

  private static final float IMAGE_STD = 1.0f;

  /** Quantized MobileNet requires additional dequantization to the output probability. */
  private static final float PROBABILITY_MEAN = 0.0f;

  private static final float PROBABILITY_STD = 255.0f;

  /**
   * Initializes a {@code ClassifierQuantizedMobileNet}.
   *
   * @param activity
   */
  public ClassifierQuantizedMobileNet(Activity activity, Device device, int numThreads)
      throws IOException {
    super(activity, device, numThreads);
  }

  @Override
  protected String getModelPath() {
    // you can download this file from
    // see build.gradle for where to obtain this file. It should be auto
    // downloaded into assets.
    return "model_quantized.tflite";
  }

  @Override
  protected String getLabelPath() {
    return "labels.txt";
  }

  @Override
  protected TensorOperator getPreprocessNormalizeOp() {
    return new NormalizeOp(IMAGE_MEAN, IMAGE_STD);
  }

  @Override
  protected TensorOperator getPostprocessNormalizeOp() {
    return new NormalizeOp(PROBABILITY_MEAN, PROBABILITY_STD);
  }
}
```

Here is the code for ClassiferFloatMobileNet.java

```java
/* Copyright 2019 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
==============================================================================*/

package org.tensorflow.lite.examples.classification.tflite;

import android.app.Activity;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.tensorflow.lite.examples.classification.tflite.Classifier.Device;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.TensorOperator;
import org.tensorflow.lite.support.common.ops.NormalizeOp;

/** This TensorFlowLite classifier works with the float MobileNet model. */
public class ClassifierFloatMobileNet extends Classifier {

  /** Float MobileNet requires additional normalization of the used input. */
  private static final float IMAGE_MEAN = 127.5f;

  private static final float IMAGE_STD = 127.5f;

  /**
   * Float model does not need dequantization in the post-processing. Setting mean and std as 0.0f
   * and 1.0f, repectively, to bypass the normalization.
   */
  private static final float PROBABILITY_MEAN = 0.0f;

  private static final float PROBABILITY_STD = 1.0f;

  /**
   * Initializes a {@code ClassifierFloatMobileNet}.
   *
   * @param activity
   */
  public ClassifierFloatMobileNet(Activity activity, Device device, int numThreads)
      throws IOException {
    super(activity, device, numThreads);
  }

  @Override
  protected String getModelPath() {
    // you can download this file from
    // see build.gradle for where to obtain this file. It should be auto
    // downloaded into assets.
    return "model.tflite";
  }

  @Override
  protected String getLabelPath() {
    return "labels.txt";
  }

  @Override
  protected TensorOperator getPreprocessNormalizeOp() {
    return new NormalizeOp(IMAGE_MEAN, IMAGE_STD);
  }

  @Override
  protected TensorOperator getPostprocessNormalizeOp() {
    return new NormalizeOp(PROBABILITY_MEAN, PROBABILITY_STD);
  }
}
```

Comment: share classifier code

Comment: @rathna I have added the code for my files

Answer (score 3):

From my own experience, the example app expects a model which returns atleast 3 classes. If yours doesn't then you'll need to either add more classes to your model or edit the code so that it works for less than 3 classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a binary classifier then the default image classifier has a nasty gotcha- no output results are shown.  You need to modify `showResultsInBottomSheet`, e.g.

```
protected void showResultsInBottomSheet(List<Recognition> results) {
    if (null == results) {
      return;
    }

    int l = results.size();

    if (l >= 2) {
      Recognition recognition = results.get(0);
      if (recognition != null) {
        if (recognition.getTitle() != null) recognitionTextView.setText(recognition.getTitle());
        if (recognition.getConfidence() != null)
          recognitionValueTextView.setText(
                  String.format("%.2f", (100 * recognition.getConfidence())) + "%");
      }

      Recognition recognition1 = results.get(1);
      if (recognition1 != null) {
        if (recognition1.getTitle() != null) recognition1TextView.setText(recognition1.getTitle());
        if (recognition1.getConfidence() != null)
          recognition1ValueTextView.setText(
                  String.format("%.2f", (100 * recognition1.getConfidence())) + "%");
      }


      if (l >= 3) {
        Recognition recognition2 = results.get(2);
        if (recognition2 != null) {
          if (recognition2.getTitle() != null)
            recognition2TextView.setText(recognition2.getTitle());
          if (recognition2.getConfidence() != null)
            recognition2ValueTextView.setText(
                    String.format("%.2f", (100 * recognition2.getConfidence())) + "%");
        }
      } else {
        recognition2TextView.setText("");
        recognition2ValueTextView.setText("");
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you replace the original model with yours? And what does "empty" means?

If you just replace the model in assets/, make sure you change the return value of #getModelPath. Also please check if there's any error log (if you use Android Studio and run the app by AS, the log will be showed in the console of AS).